# R convert rows to columns

Tags: r

I am new to "R",
I need to convert rows to columns 
Source is saved in data frame

What i am able to do

`destination<- as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(~order_id+dish_id, source))`

But , i unable to get what i desired 
So can any1 help me to get data like in destination

Source:-

```
order_id    primary_dish    dish_id  category_id
328507       38118            38114   1536
328523       38081            38068   1829
328523       38094            38068   1829
```

(Source data looks in above format)

Destination :-

```
order_id    primary_dish    38114   38068   1536   1829
328507        38118           1       0       1     0
328523        38081           0       1       0     1
328523        38094           0       1       0     1
```

Comment: Are you trying to transpose? If yes, try t(dataframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: In order to use that "long-to-wide" link @jogo provided, you'll want to first go from "wide-to-long", effectively combining `category_id` and `dish_id` into a single column. Then you can easily convert from "long-to-wide" as already suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work to get you the desired output.

```
library (dplyr)
library (tidyr)
destination <- destination %>%
    mutate (dval = 1) %>%
    spread (key = dish_id, value = dval, fill = 0) %>%
    mutate (cval = 1) %>%
    spread (key = category_id, value = cval, fill = 0) %>%
    arrange (order_id, primary_dish)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot 
This is what i was looking for